# How to type "as const" in a generic way in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let say I have multiple objects defined with "as const" like this:

```
export const FooSettings = {
  Sound: 0x4,
  Rotate: 0x2,
  Blink: 0x1,
} as const;

export const BarSettings = {
  Supervised: 0x4,
  Bell: 0x2,
  TwoWay: 0x1,
} as const;
```

I also have a static method in a class that will take a settings object and a string and give me a string back with all settings enabled by that string.

```
// NOTE: flags have "any" type
static parseNames (flags: any, value: string): string {
  const hexNumber = parseInt(value, 16);
  const flagNames: string[] = [];

  for (const key in flags) {
    if (hexNumber & flags[key]) {
      flagNames.push(key);
    }
  }

  return flagNames.join('|');
}
```

It works, but I have no idea about how I should type the "flags" argument to only accept objects as my both settings and any other object as const.

Comment: It looks like you should use an `enum` instead of the object literals, and a generic type for `parseNames`

Comment: Are you looking for `{[k: string]: number}` maybe as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mAP1PN)?  This doesn't care about `as const` (nor would such a thing really matter much); all you care about is that it's an object with numerics values at all its keys, right?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. That is correct and it works as expected.

Comment: [Answers belong in answer posts, not as edits to the question.  Please consider undoing your most recent edit.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74101/511366)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you care about is that `flags` is an object whose property values are all `number`s, then you can give it an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) type like

```
flags: { [k: string]: number }
```

Then your `parseNames` method will still compile, and you'll get the desired behavior on the caller's side:

```
X.parseNames(BarSettings, "5"); // okay
X.parseNames(FooSettings, "5"); // okay
X.parseNames({ a: 1, b: 2 }, "3"); // okay

Foo.parseNames({ a: 1, b: "oops" }, "3") // error!
// string vs number -> ~
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAYiEBlAplKBLMBzCMC8MA3gLABQMlMSIArmACYBcMADAB4AsANOVTACUQUAIZQULDgCZeFKgCEANlgDWk9gEZZAXxgi8oSFADc5coegx5IgE6p0WXAWJ8qSWgAcUNgG4YIKMxsXLL88iiKiuoyrpQAKgDuIADqIgCe6lrkuvowFiZmZMCK+ngIIC5ylNBiGMAwHrYBAHIiALYoEAAUAGYluCxEMADaajDQNo4AuixgtG0ARt4w2twwPiKKtBLjUJM4AJQsE46V-Pz5MAAWKOzN80s2zo02AQCSYFBdG1soaxoANgOpiq50ufRE2FaHQgxz2jmGU2ciJBsXOPRATy6lxUKDSMCwMAhuAOZ3O5IwPRgXRudweywAZET+hBRnipqTSKDyeTidDOgA6Dy0CBXLq4tLAtE8lbSqjaQoymxoWg2MDMyH8iACgBWICwXQA5AAfQ1S0EKsiW8zgCAgRQoAWKEDYLrlIVNFBarrWOxoTA4CBrABEAFZgwdgTAAPTR6iebx+AIMY2JFLpG2Qe2O52u90vFrtTpuxD2AO4EPhyPGGNxmj0FNKVSZu0Op0uksgD2vL1F7pDEQsLQwBYsKQrEMAZgjpNjemNC0K+c93oHQ7Wo5gwcQHggwYnW+ns7j3hsmIAhOQ5yccOs8HNFssALQAPhgAD9yEA)